# How to prevent TD to wrap 2 div's

Tags: html, css

I'm having a table with a td having two div's. I want both of that div to be in line, but the 2nd div gets wrapped as no of columns increases. I don't want to set the  fixed width for each column though.

HTML td structure:

```
<td class="tableHead"> 
  <div class="tableHeadTxt">Lorem Ipsum</div> 
  <div class="toggler togglerImgCollapse"> </div>  
</td>
```

Comment: Why are you using `div` rather than `span`?

Comment: Even span also causing same problem

Answer (score 3):

Hey now you can do this as like this

**Used** `white-space:nowrap;` in **your css** fine and give to **parent div** this properties

and **child div** define `display:inline-block;` in  your **css file**

**Css**

```
.tableHead{
border:solid 1px red;
    white-space:nowrap;
}



td.tableHead > div{
border:solid 1px green;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>

<td class="tableHead">
  <div class="tableHeadTxt">Lorem Ipsum</div>
  <div class="toggler togglerImgCollapse">Lorem Ipsum </div>  
</td>
    </tr></table>
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/2965K/

Answer (score 2):

1. `div.tableHeadTxt` should get a `white-space: nowrap;` CSS. This will make it not wrap the text, so the second `div` is forced to.
2. `td.tableHead div.tableHeadTxt, td.tableHead div.toggler` should get a `float: left;` CSS. This ensures it will render inline.
3. You need a third `div` following the other two, which has a `clear: both; height: 0; width: 100%;` CSS attached to it. This ensures that the `td` retains proper height despite having only inline elements.

Answer (score 1):

use float in your divs

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="tableHead">
            <div class="tableHeadTxt" style="float:left">Lorem Ipsum</div>
            <div class="toggler togglerImgCollapse" style="float:left">pbaris</div>  
        </td>       
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gkzdG/

Answer (score 0):

I am using these lines:

```
<div style="background: transparent url("../Images/20_20.png") no-repeat center; height: 20px; width:80px; ">
        <span  style=" background: transparent url("../Images/ObjectType/10_10.png") no-repeat center; height: 20px; width:80px; height: 20px; width:20px; margin-left:40px; ">  &nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Hope it can help you.